# How do I change the resolution of an image in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, resolution

I wish to change the resolution of an image before displaying it.
when I use this code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
...
my_image = my_image.resize((128, 128), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

I get the message:

```
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'resize'
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: You need to do the resize on the original PIL `Image`, not the `ImageTk` you created from it.  I can't be any more specific, since you didn't show the relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
PIL.Image.open('Your image location').resize(128,128)
```